# numpy testing assert array NOT equal

Tags: python, numpy, python-unittest

We have [`numpy.testing.assert_array_equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_equal.html#numpy.testing.assert_array_equal) to assert that two arrays are equal.

But what is the best way to do `numpy.testing.assert_array_not_equal`, that is, to make sure that two arrays are NOT equal?

Comment: How unequal are the arrays? Must they differ in every element, or at least in one?

Comment: At least one element should be unequal. That is, the content of the two arrays may not be the same. If one element differ, everything is OK.

Comment: Then @Eswcvlad's answer is probably the most elegant hack you will find.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to use specifically NumPy testing, then you can use `numpy.testing.assert_array_equal` together with [numpy.testing.assert_raises](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_raises.html#numpy.testing.assert_raises) for the opposite result. For example:

```
assert_raises(AssertionError, assert_array_equal, array_1, array_2)
```

Also there is `numpy.testing.utils.assert_array_compare` (it is used by `numpy.testing.assert_array_equal`), but I don't see it documented anywhere, so use with caution. This one will check that every element is different, so I guess this is not your use case:

```
import operator

assert_array_compare(operator.__ne__, array_1, array_2)
```

Comment: Neat hack for first method. Second one will only succeed if every element, not just some, is different as far as I can tell. Not sure if that is what OP wants. +1 either way.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the second one. Will edit the answer.

Comment: The first one does it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I don't think there is anything built directly into the NumPy testing framework but you could just use:

```
np.any(np.not_equal(a1,a2))
```

and assert true with the built in unittest framework or check with NumPy as `assert_equal` to `True` e.g.

```
np.testing.assert_equal(np.any(np.not_equal(a,a)), True)
```

Comment: You should probably just use `TestCase.assertTrue(np.any(…))` instead (or `nose.tools.assert_true(np.any(…))` if you are outside of a `TestCase`).

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why this hasn't been posted, may be I didn't understand the question properly, but what about:

```
assert not np.array_equal(array1 , array2)
```

Any reason why you would like to keep it exclusively in the testing module of numpy?

Comment: `assert_array_equal` handles NaN as values, not as uncomparable (always unequal to anything) like usual for floating point

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner syntax to @Eswcvlad's answer:

```py
import numpy as np

with np.testing.assert_raises(AssertionError):
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(expected, actual)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you usually want to test if something is almost equal (considering decimal precision) and consequently want to test if something is NOT almost equal in some cases. Building on @Mikhail answer (and also using pytest.raises) this would give:

```
import numpy as np
import pytest
 
with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
   np.testing.assert_almost_equal(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507093/11671779), we can make `assert_array_not_equal` as follows

```py
from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal, assert_raises


def assert_array_not_equal(x, y):
    return assert_raises(AssertionError, assert_array_equal, x, y)
```